# Медленная работа SwiftMailer для почты mail.ru

Tags: email, php, yii, mail.ru

Всем привет. У меня есть некий домен (example.com). Использую почту mail.ru для своего домена, соответствующие записи в настройках домена прописал.

Для отправки писем на сервере использую **SwiftMailer**, но он **очень медленно** работает. Отправки письма занимает около **4-5 секунд**, что достаточно критично для веб-приложении.

Может кто-то знает, в следствие чего такая задержка и как можно уменьшить время отправки письма. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Когда работаешь через сторонний сервис, причин для тормозов может быть очень много. Возможно это тормоза из-за географического расстояния между своим сервером и серверами сервиса; возможно - медленная обработка данных со стороны сервиса, может быть там какие-то внутренние ограничения на обработку по smtp.

Чтобы эти тормоза не влияли на скорость рендера страницы, обычно используют **очереди**.

Можно написать свой велосипед для очередей. Вместо отправки пишем письмо eml-файл в какую-то предопределенную директорию. Это гораздо быстрее чем отправка по smtp. А непосредственно отправкой пусть занимается консольная команда, которая будет запускаться через крон.

Также посмотрите в сторону RabbitMQ. Это одна из наиболее распространенных реализаций работы с очередями.

Comment: Большое спасибо! А крон можно запускать раз в минуту?

Comment: Да, можно.